# Vim can not recognize comment "//end" when autoindent full verilog code

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I'm now using gvim to write verilog code. When i use the **auto indent full text function** (command: gg=G), gvim starts to auto indent the full text. However, gvim can recognize "// begin" but can not recognize "// end", which leads to wrong code indents. e.g.(after input command gg=G):

```
always@(posedge iClk) begin
    some codes.....
    if(condition....) begin
        some codes....
    end
    //if(condition..) begin
        //some commented out codes...
        //end
        if(condition...) begin
            some codes...
        end
    end
```

Gvim can recognize the **begin** in **//if(condition) begin**, and auto indents the next line **//some commented out code...**. But when comes to **//end**, gvim falls to recognize and makes wrong code indents to all the codes below the **//end**.

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem, please?

Comment: Can you include your setup relating to how you identify file as verilog and any special verilog syntax files you load in your .vimrc

Comment: Sorry Morgan, I don't know how vim identifies verilog files, I haven't config anything about that. All configurations are default. When I open the files with filename extension .v, vim automatically identifies the file type.

Comment: And no special syntax for verilog in .vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug with the standard verilog indent function, part of the standard vim distribution at `runtime/indent/verilog.vim`.

A search for verilog indent files on www.vim.org shows [four options](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=verilog&script_type=indent), including one labeled "bugfixes to vim indent for verilog : bugfixes: previous version was evaluating expressions inside comments".  You could try that one, but it is the lowest-rated of the options.  You could also try GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, benjifisher! The indent file on vim.org does solve this problem. I don't know why this is the lowest-rated option, but this file works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to [benjifishers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559281/97073) since you are not specifying the indentation file the default version will be used `runtime/indent/verilog.vim`.

If you have not already install [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), I recommend that you do so, it makes switching syntax & indentation files very easy.

Basically it will allow you to add plugins as a single folder into `~/.vim/bundle`, which also implies removeing the ones you do not want is easy as deleting a single folder. This is useful when trying out language plugins otherwise they often require files to be put in:

```
~/.vim/ftdetect
~/.vim/ftplugin
~/.vim/indent
~/.vim/syntax
```

The [Verilog](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=394) option on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=verilog&script_type=indent) is probably lowly rated because it does not support SystemVerilog Keywords.

I have a [SystemVerilog plugin](https://github.com/morganp/SystemVerilog.vim) which I use but do not think the re-indent function is fixed there.

Mine is based on [nickjones verilog_systemverilog](https://github.com/nickjones/verilog_systemverilog.vim).
**The latest under active development looks like [nachumk's systemverilog.vim](https://github.com/nachumk/systemverilog.vim).**

NB: for re-indentation I have this setup in my .vimrc which re-indents from `;g` and keeps current position in the file.

```
"http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/preserve-a-vim-function-that-keeps-your-state/
function! Preserve(command)
  " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
  let _s=@/
  let l = line(".")
  let c = col(".")
  " Do the business:
  execute a:command
  " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
  let @/=_s
  call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

map ;g :call Preserve("normal! gg=G")<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you, Morgan! It's very nice of you to reply me and tell me the solution on system verilog and the plugin. I'll try .vim file in your answer. Thanks!